# Sort by two or more variables

Tags: stata

I'm trying to sort by `ID` and then by `Date`.

What I have:

```
| ID     | Date         |
| ----------------------|
| 112    | 2013-01-01   |
| 112    | 2013-01-15   |
| 113    | 2012-01-01   |
| 112    | 2014-02-13   |
| 112    | 2013-01-02   |
| 113    | 2011-01-11   |
```

What I need:

```
| ID     | Date         |
| ----------------------|
| 112    | 2013-01-01   |
| 112    | 2013-01-02   |
| 112    | 2013-01-15   |
| 112    | 2014-02-13   |
| 113    | 2011-01-11   |
| 113    | 2012-01-01   |
```

My problem is that I only know how to sort by `ID` or `Date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally:

```
clear

input id foo
1 56
1 34
2 13
1 67
1 22
2 89
2 61
2 76
end

sort id (foo)

list, sepby(id)

     +----------+
     | id   foo |
     |----------|
  1. |  1    22 |
  2. |  1    34 |
  3. |  1    56 |
  4. |  1    67 |
     |----------|
  5. |  2    13 |
  6. |  2    61 |
  7. |  2    76 |
  8. |  2    89 |
     +----------+
```

In a more advanced programming context you can use the same syntax with `bysort`.